# Start Docker with AUFS Storage Driver

Tags: docker

All questions/answers I have found on Internet doesn't works for me.

I want start Docker with AUFS Storage Driver to finish Discourse (forum) installation.

I've add *{"storage-driver": "aufs"}*

into **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

I have this when I restart Docker:

```
Jan 21 19:08:21 discourse systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 21 19:08:21 discourse systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 21 19:08:21 discourse systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use that particular storeage driver? instead of overlay2?, it says [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) that `overlay2` is recommended on kernel 4+.

Comment: I want use other value instead of VFS. Discourse don't start if I use VFS.

Comment: You can tell what filesystem you are using by running "docker info" and looking                                                                                                                                                              at the 'Storage Driver' line.

Comment: does your version satisfy all the requirement listed here:  https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/ ?

Comment: I've proceed to installation with this tutoriel, but the default storage is VFS and not overlay2 for example...

Comment: i have this on mine `{"storage-driver": "overlay2"}
`

Comment: Yes, I want the same, but if I create daemon.json file in /etc/docker, Docker refuse to restart...

Comment: I'm already blocked to install Docker with another storage driver :/